# How do I make sure code copied from web is acknowledged in my code?

Tags: python, comments

Not sure this is the right platform to ask, but here I go.

I found this [solution online](https://gist.github.com/yulkang/2e4fc3061b45403f455d7f4c316ab168) for vectorizing some tensor operations I am working on as part of a much bigger research project.

I would like to make sure that when someone reads my code, it is clear those functions are not mine.

What is the pythonic way to approach the issue? A docstring comment?

Comment: A docstring for the functions and you could keep them in their own module and the module can also have a docstring.